# How can I set the order of keys that are insert to field with json data type?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5.3

This is what my database looks like:

[image: This is my database]

My code to insert is like this :

```
$attribute = [
    'type'=>'customer',
    'keys'=>[
        'year'=>(string)$event->customer->year,
        'month'=>(string)$event->customer->month,
        'codeprogram'=>(string)$event->customer->codeprogram,
        'codeoutput'=>(string)$event->customer->codeoutput,
        'codeaccount'=>(string)$event->customer->codeaccount
    ],
    'summary'=>$event->customer->value,
];

Summary::create($attribute);
```

I have 4 field in table summary : id, type, keys, summary

data type of keys is json

When executed, data that is insert into field keys is like this :

> {"codeprogram": "1", "codeoutput": "4", "codeaccount": "7", "year":
>   "2017", "month": "1"}

Sometimes like :

> {"codeoutput": "4",  "year": "2017", "codeprogram": "1", "month": "1",
>   "codeaccount": "7"}

The inserted data looks random

I want the inserted data to field keys in sequence like this :

> {"year": "2017", "month": "1", "codeprogram": "1", "codeoutput": "4",
>   "codeaccount": "7"}

How can I do it?

Comment: how do you select your data?

Comment: @hassan, What I ask is how to set the order when insert data. Not taking data

Comment: what do you mean by insertion order? in mysql insertion order is depending on the order of table columns, in another words there are no insertion order,

Comment: do you insert your data as a json string? or as an array ?

Comment: @hassan, as an array. I set in model like this : `protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'type' => 'string',
        'keys' => 'array'
    ];`

Comment: the `keys` field, you are inserting it as an array or as an json string ?

Comment: @hassan, As an array string. You can see my code

Comment: please show a screen-shot of your Summary table structure :)

Comment: @hassan, https://postimg.org/image/ueqa33lez/

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of the keys in a JSON object has no meaning.  Many implementations do not serialize objects in a deterministic order, for that reason.

> An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace). Each name is followed by `:` (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` (comma). *[emphasis added]*
>
> — http://json.org

Consider the following pseudocode that deserializes a JSON string into a data structure, then serializes that data structure back into JSON:

```
let a = '{ "x": "hello", "y": "world" }'

let b = to_json(from_json(a))
```

There are two possible values for `b`:

```
'{ "x": "hello", "y": "world" }'
'{ "y": "world", "x": "hello" }'
```

Both results are valid and both results are equivalent.

---

Note that storing a JSON string in a database column is generally considered an antipattern unless the database is never going to be queried against the content of the JSON.  The content of any given column should be an atomic value.  This is only true for a JSON object if the database queries are not predicated upon the contents of the object's attribute/value pairs.

Comment: So the conclusion is that data that is inserted into field keys can not be sorted?